# collection of sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How to solve this exercise?

If $A$ is a collection of $\sigma$-algebra. Show that $\bigcap A=\bigcap_{F\in A}F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Do you mean $\bigcap A=\bigcap_{F\in A}F$?

Comment: @ervx yes, sorry for my typo..

Comment: What do you know about $\sigma$-algebras? What properties to we need to check to see whether or not $\bigcap A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @ervx I guess to prove $\bigcap A$ is closed under complement?

Comment: So if you take a set $B\in\cap A$, then it must be that $B\in F$ for each $F$ in $A$. But each such $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, so $B^{c}\in F$ for each such $F$. Thus, $B^{c}\in \cap A$. Does that make sense? This is part of what you need to show. What else?

Comment: Best lecture videos on measure theory https://youtu.be/llnNaRzuvd4. The third lesson contains what you ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $\emptyset \in \bigcap A$ (?).

Given $E\in \bigcap A$, $E\in F$ for all $F\in A$ hence $E^c$ is in each $F$, i.e., $E^c \in \bigcap A$.

Given a sequence $(E_j) \in \bigcap A$, each $E_j$ is in every $F$, so the sequence is contained in all $F$ and hence $\bigcup E_j \in F \; \forall F\in A$, that's equivalent to say that $\bigcup E_i \in \bigcap A$...

So $\bigcap A$ is closed under complement and countable union.